# CollectionView Reloaddata - Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift

I add the data that I have drawn from Database to CollectionView. I am putting the data I have added as an array in the model array. I see the data inside Array in collectionView. Sometimes data is added smoothly but sometimes I get the error

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

. Sometimes while working sometimes why not? I think there is a problem with collectionView.reloadData ().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtuWd.png)

```
@IBOutlet weak var sonsuzCollec: UICollectionView!
var model = [[String]]()
var davetiyefilee = [String]()
var davetiyefilee2 = [String]()

extension denemeView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    if (collectionView == sonsuzCollec) {
        return model[section].count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        if (collectionView == sonsuzCollec) {
            return yeniDavKATIsımNew.count
        }
        return 0
    }
...
}

@objc func davetiyeCEK1() {
    if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
        for review in baslik {
            if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                self.davetiyefilee.append(s)
            }
        }
        self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.sonsuzCollec?.reloadData() 
        }  
    }
}

@objc func davetiyeCEK2() {
    if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
        for review in baslik {
            if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                self.davetiyefilee2.append(s)
            } 
        }
        self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee2)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.sonsuzCollec?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your model array? You already have the information you need in davetiyefilee and davetiyefilee2. The way your'e adding data to your model array is what's giving you trouble.

Comment: I add it in this way so that I can collect and indexpath.section in the model array @Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is beacuse of your model array's section item is empty.
how many collection you are using? can you show more full code

or maybe another approch is in your numberofsection try this

```
if (collectionView == sonsuzCollec) {
        var numberofRows = 0
        if model[section].count > 0 {
            numberofRows = model[section].count
        } else {
             numberofRows = 0
        }
        return  numberofRows
    }
```